# N-Tier questions

Tags: architecture

In a typical N-Tier app, my understanding of the tiers is as follows:

DAL - code which interacts with db
BLL - business rules (how is this different to the DAL? Does it call the DAL? What's a sample BLL class?)

Presentation Layer

Also, where does a "service layer" come into all of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's start with DAL.
It lets you forget all the problems with DB when you write you BLL. That is: DAL takes care of insert, select, update, delete operations, takes care of transactions, executes stored procedures ets.
How do you use it in real life? Let's say tou have a table TBL1 in your DB. In DAL you create a class, named Tbl1Adapter. With dummy methods CreateRecord, GetRecord(id), UpdateRecord(id, newData), DeleteRecord(Id). Your BLL will call this methods. But Tbl1Adapter class will do DB job inside. It will call stored procedures or will send SQL commands to DB or will use some tricky DB drivers to fullfill your wishes from BLL :) Besides DAL does not mean only databases, it may be used to work with ASCII files, with input devices, with something else. 
This layer provides data.

Next thing is BLL:
BLL is all about working your data. It gets data from DAL, and gives data to DAL to save it. But all the operations with data appear in BLL: numbers get multiplied, conditions (IF...THEN...) fullfiled, some other rocket science logic is executed... So BLL is core of your application. 
This layer is a brain of your application.

Presentation layer:
This one is the easiest one to understand and very interesting to develop. It is all about how your application presents results of it's work. It may be a windows form with data grid and buttons, it may be a web page, it may be some cool audio interface.
This layer is a face of your application: eyes and ears to get data from user (or another system), and mouth to give data to user (or another system).

Well, service layer is a little bit tricky one.
Often it is an API of some other application. Let's say I have a web-service which can multiply to numbers. It's called MegaBrain :)
You have an application, which takes two numbers from user. But instead of implementing BLL in your application you decide TO USE SERVICE of my MegaBrain - give him those numbers and get back the result.
So service layer is... well, I don't know how to describe it in two words. Service layer let's your application use BLL of another application. It is similar to DAL, but data access layer only stores and gives data, while service layer performs some operations on input data and produces some result (gives you back result of multiplication or turns on a TV ;)

Comment: Good explanation, I see, service layer would be a link between the original app and the outside apps.